# AndroidStudio Show Logcat in Finder

Tags: android, logcat

is there a way, can let me see my logcat logs in finder.
just like androidStudio's "Show Log in Finder".
but the "Show Log in Finder" just show the idea log. And what I want
is my logcat logs. Is there a way? any helps thank you.

Comment: This forum is related to programming questions only.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to show your AndroidStudio logcat files in finder. You can certainly run logcat at the command line and save them to a file. You would do something like this

```
cd $ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools
adb logcat -v threadtime |tee logcat.txt
```

If you are looking to do more advanced things with your logs have a look at [LogRabbit](http://lograbbit.com/) which will allow you to save (or import) your logs.

[LogRabbit](http://lograbbit.com/) also provides a way to search your Android logs. It has strong search capabilities as well as a very rich real-time filter functionality. You can look on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZVr2R6DumNZUoMZRndqM7cL63gp2NTYE) for some examples of what it can do.